# Django Login, template doesn't recognize logged user

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-login

I'm writing an app that handles user autentificacion, and now I'm trying to do that feature.

My urlpatterns is this:

login page template, calls a html with a form that makes a POST to get username and password

```
url(r'^$', views.login_page, name='login_page'),
```

called from login form, recieves POST data (username, password) authenticate a user, does login and redirects to index page

```
url(r'^auth', views.auth_user, name='auth'),
```

index page, here we have to be logged to see it's content

```
url(r'^index$', views.index, name='index'),
```

So it seems to work, I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/AcademyApp/ to start, it shows login form, login form send data to auth view, makes auth, login and redirects to index, but index its like it can't read logged user data, I'm trying to do:

```
<h1>HI {{user.username}} !!</h1>
```

and it shows nothing, just blank.

I readed in django tutorial but I think it's not so much complete this feature, or I don't understand it at all :(

Here I put some important pieces of code:

**ACADEMYAPP/URLS.PY**

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.login_page, name='login_page'),
    url(r'^auth', views.auth_user, name='auth'),
    url(r'^index$', views.index, name='index'),
```

**HTML_LOGIN_FORM**

```
<form action="/AcademyApp/auth" method="post">
    username: 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
    password:
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def login_page(request):
    template = loader.get_template('AcademyApp/login.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())


def auth_user(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
            return redirect("index")

        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            template = loader.get_template('AcademyApp/error.html')
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        template = loader.get_template('AcademyApp/error.html')

    return HttpResponse(template.render())


@login_required
def index(request, user):
    template = loader.get_template('AcademyApp/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Thanks for your help mates

Comment: Here is my project in github if anyone wants to take a look. Thanks!
https://github.com/rul3s/GestAcademy

Comment: Read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the template to gain access to the `user` variable, you need to render it with a RequestContext. But you're not passing *any* context at all. Instead of calling the template loader and render methods directly, you should use the [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

```
def index(request, user):
    return render(request, 'AcademyApp/index.html', {})
```

Comment: second time you help me today, thanks you a lot.
I had read almost 5 times djanto auth documentation and I didnt notice about this at all...